# Sync Microsoft Access Database on a local network with a MySQL database on a web server

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, synchronization

I'm a front-end web developer trying to devise a solution to sync a Microsoft Access Database on a local network with a MySQL database on a web server. I ran across some software that might perform this however it looks complicated to maintain and seems like it could be an additional point of failure.

There is also a way MS Access can use an ODBC to an external MySQL database. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables....

If the ODBC connection to the external MySQL database works, is there a way to sync an external DB table with a local DB table so when a change occurs with one it's pushed to the other?

Or is there another recommendation to handle this process?

Thank you.

Comment: Which database is the master version? If its your local Access database you could just set a CRON/scheduled task to copy the databases across but yes probably using an external program. I've used some Access to MySQL programs which help. Alternatively you could use PHP to connect to the Access database and import it across to the MySQL tables.

Comment: Just use linked tables in Access, and work directly with the MySQL tables. Any replication setup will encounter conflicts, and resolving conflicts across different RDBMS solutions will be a pain.

Comment: Erik von Asmuth, It sounds like linked tables in Access make sense... 1. If linked tables are used between the local Access database and the MySQL database on the web server, can or will changes be logged anywhere? 2. How does access know to update the linked table on the local Access database if a change is made on the MySQL web server? Is it constantly checking for changes made to MySQL database? 3. Can an Access table (within MS Access) be copied to the MySQL table so there's duplicate table to start with?